# Incompatible pointer type with pthread_create (C)

Tags: c, pointers, pthreads, posix

I'm working on a personal project that uses multi threading to split an array, search for a target, and return the number of matches. I've got one bug and a few errors with my early code.

Errors...

```
main.c:117:10: warning: passing argument 1 of 'pthread_create' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

In file included from main.c:5:0: /usr/include/pthread.h:225:12: note: expected 'pthread_t * restrict' but argument is of type 'pthread_t **'
```

I'm very new to POSIX and have no clue what's wrong here.

Bug...

My big loop that is supposed to loop as long as index < totalElems only loops once. It goes into the small loop and drops out of both instead of looping more. I'm not sure why this is.

Header file...

```
#ifndef COUNT_ARRAY_H
#define COUNT_ARRAY_H


// structure declarations
typedef struct
{
 int     threadNum;
 int     *array;
 int     first;
 int     last;
 int     target;
 int     numFound;

} ThreadInfo;


// function prototypes
void*   ThreadFunc(void  *vptr);


#endif  // COUNT_ARRAY_H
```

.
.

Main.c file....

```
#include    <pthread.h>
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    "count_array.h"

int     main(void)
{
 auto    int                 numSegs;
 auto    int                 numSegElems;
 auto    int                 maxRand;
 auto    int                 target;
 auto    int                 totalElems;
 auto    int                 totalFound = 0;
 auto    ThreadInfo          *infoPtr;
 auto    pthread_t           *threadHandles;
 auto    int                 index = 0;
 auto    int                 first;
 auto    int                 last;
 auto    int                 threadNum = 0;

//get primary info from user...
printf(" Please enter the total number of elements? ");
scanf("%d", &totalElems);

printf(" Please enter the maximum random value: ");
scanf("%d", &maxRand);

printf(" Please enter the number of segments (1 to 15857): ");
scanf("%d", &numSegs);

 if(numSegs > 15857)
   {
    puts(" Too many segments for machine!");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

numSegElems = totalElems/numSegs;

// configure the array to work with
// declare array here...

auto int myArray[totalElems];

//and fill array here
for(; index < totalElems; index++)
   {
    // % rand() and maxRand to get good range and
    //not go beyond users max number
    myArray[index] = (rand() % maxRand);

    //test printf...ignore if still here at 5/18/17 or later
     printf(" %d \n", myArray[index]);
   }

// get the target value to look for
 printf(" Please enter the target value: ");
 scanf("%d",&target);

// display initial information
printf("*** Begin search: target = %d, # elements = %d, # segments = %d, "
                                            "# segment elements = %d\n"
                                                            , target
                                                            , totalElems
                                                            , numSegs
                                                            , numSegElems);


// initialize the array first/last indexes into the integer array
// >>>50 elems total/5 = 10 threads total and 5 elems in each thread<<<
  for(index = 0; index < totalElems; index++)
     {

      first = myArray[0];

      if(index == numSegElems)
        {

         puts(" in if ");
         last = myArray[index];

         printf(" %d \n", index);


// allocate an array to store the thread handles

         auto int arraySeg[numSegElems];

 // loop and create threads (# of segments)

    // allocate a thread info structure from the heap
    //using malloc

         infoPtr = malloc(sizeof(ThreadInfo));
         if(NULL == infoPtr)
           {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate ThreadInfo struct for "
                           "thread #%d\n", threadNum);

            continue;
           }
    // store the information in the allocated structure
         infoPtr->target = target;
         infoPtr->threadNum = threadNum;
         infoPtr->first = first;
         infoPtr->last = last;
         infoPtr->array = arraySeg;

    // create the secondary thread, passing the thread info
       if(pthread_create(&threadHandles, NULL, ThreadFunc, &infoPtr))
         {
          fprintf(stderr, "Error: failed to create thread #%d\n", 
          threadNum);
          continue;
         }

    // update the first/last array indexes for the next thread
    //set to zero again??

      }//end small loop to make individual threads

    //increment thread #
       ++threadNum;

    }//end big loop
      // loop and join the threads to fetch each thread's results

    // join with the next thread

        // get the total number of matches from the thread's infoPtr
        // and display a message

        // release the infoPtr structure back to the heap


// display the final results

// release heap memory


   return 0;

}  // end of "main"
```

I've done a smaller project like this before, but I'm not seeing what's wrong here. I need to pass infoPtr and use the members in ThreadFunc. I'm doing this like my other programs exactly, but it's not working. I've tried searching the site and google, but maybe I can't figure it out because it's too specific? Also, removing the & doesn't help. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `note: expected 'pthread_t * restrict' but argument is of type 'pthread_t **'` Isn't that a very clear message that tells you exactly what the problem is?

Comment: This isn't any of your problems, but the keyword `auto` is obsolete and has had no effect whatsoever for many, many years.  I think this may be the first time I've _ever_ seen someone use it in a C program.

Comment: @kaylum Does it mean not have a & on "threadhandles"? Because if I take it away, it says threadhandles is uninitialized. I had it as "&threadhandles" in my other programs and it doesn't work in this one. I read the value into numSegElems, but left it out here to not make my post insanely large.

Comment: You need to declare it as: `pthread_t threadHandles[totalElems];` and then pass it into `pthread_create` as `&threadHandles[index]`. And please don't post incomplete code. You need to create a [mcve].

Comment: @zwol I took the class last semester with an old professor who insisted on using auto storage class, it's a habit now.

Comment: Suggest you break out of that habit. Not all habits are healthy.

Comment: A concrete reason why you should stop using `auto` is that it now means something _completely different_ (and actually useful) in C++, so you will confuse people by using it with its original K&R meaning. When I saw it, for a moment I thought I was reading a C++ program, or a program written by someone confused about the difference between the two languages (we get that a lot here).

Comment: Indentation...............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm not seeing what's wrong here.

There are *many* things wrong here.

Let's consider a very reduced test case:

```
pthread_t *threadHandles;
ThreadInfo *info;

for(index = 0; index < totalElems; index++) {
  info = malloc(sizeof(ThreadInfo));
  pthread_create(&threadHandles, NULL, ThreadFunc, &info);
}
return 0;
```

Problems:

- You create N threads, then return without waiting for any of them. As soon as `main` returns, *all* threads evaporate with it (the entire program terminates).
- On each iteration of the loop, pthread_create assigns a *new* value to the same `threadHandles` variable. You lose the previous value, and thus the ability to wait for that thread (this is also producing the compiler warning that is the subject of your question).
- You pass the *same* `info` value into each of the threads, thus leaking memory you allocated for them, and creating a data race between them.

Here is a fix for above problems (there may be other problems that I didn't spot immediately):

```
pthread_t *threadHandles;
ThreadInfo *info;

threadHandles = calloc(totalElems, sizeof(pthread_t));
info = calloc(totalElems, sizeof(ThreadInfo));

for(index = 0; index < totalElems; index++) {
  info[index].threadNum = threadNum;
  // Initialize other elements of info here.
  pthread_create(&threadHandles[index], NULL, ThreadFunc, &info[index]);
}
// Wait for threads to finish
for(index = 0; index < totalElems; index++) {
  pthread_join(threadHanles[index], NULL);
}
// Free memory
free(threadHandles);
free(info);
return 0;
```

Comment: Oh, wow! I did not realize I need to join them as soon as one finished. I'm very unfamiliar with pthreads, thank you for that. Could you explain why you used calloc? I was using malloc before, maybe calloc is better since I need to define first and last indexes first?

Comment: @Maddy `calloc` is simply a convenient way to allocate arrays. Whether you use `malloc` or `calloc` is immaterial here.